# Custom MGLAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapbox

How can I open new View, by tapping on Annotation Point in MapBox. I need to show the personal page of this or that place on the map. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/callout-delegate/) from the Mapbox website shows how to give the callout some functionality. The example just shows an alert when you tap it but you would just trigger your segue instead.